# remove first line from text file and put rest of words into an array that separated from white-spaces,

Tags: c#, regex, streamreader

I have text file in a following format

`432
23 34 45 56 78 90
67 87 90 76 43 09
.................`

I want to remove first line and insert rest of the words into an array that separated from white space.

I wrote following code to get words by removing white spaces

```
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\sample.txt"); //get the file
    string stringWithMultipleSpaces = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); //load file to string
    streamReader.Close();

    Regex newrow = new Regex(" +"); //specify delimiter (spaces)
    string[] splitwords = r.Split(stringWithMultipleSpaces); //(convert string to array of words)
```

once I put a debug point on `string[] splitwords` line i can see following out put

[image]

How can I remove first line and get rest of the words from array index `[0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split with all whitespaces, not just a plain space.

Use `@"\s+"` pattern to match 1+ whitespace symbol(s):

```
string[] splitwords = Regex.Split(stringWithMultipleSpaces, @"\s+");
```

Another approach is reading the file line by line, and - if there are always only numbers like those and no Unicode spaces present - use plain `String.Split()`.

Something like

```
var results = new List<string>();
using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\sample.txt", true))
{
    var s  = string.Empty;
    while ((s=sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        results.AddRange(s.Split());
    }
}
```

Comment: very accurate and prompt :)

Comment: Note that `true` argument in `new StreamReader()` is used to read from a Unicode file. You will need to pass `Encoding.Default` if you need to read from an ANSI-encoded file.

Comment: Mind that reading the whole file in and parsing it with a regex causes ... [this reaction](http://www.relatably.com/m/img/regular-expression-memes/187c7aef8a6985ba6f252fa41f8a0620eaf8f4091203e5403e23374e70ffb954.jpg) :) If your files are huge, read line by line and store the results in an SQL (sqlite) DB.